# How to put URL in bibtex bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I'm having trouble to correctly finish my bibliography.
In the website's region, I cannot place the url correctly.
Can anyone help me out?
I've search some questions, but I wasn't able to get the answer...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}
\begin{document}
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip}
\phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{References}                           
    \end{singlespace}
\end{document
```

Reference example:

```
@ONLINE{Asus:Online,
title = {ASUS “Xtion PRO LIVE”. },
month = April,
year = {2014},
url = {http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/#specifications;}
}
```

and the result is..[image]

Comment: Your code is neither minimal nor compilable. Also it's not clear what the entry should look like.

Comment: @Bernard please tell how should I place the code here so that some1 can replicate the problem :/

Comment: Remove everything that has nothing to see with the bibliography and isn't required to compile.The singlespace` environment is a good example: it's not related to your problem and you don't even load the package that defines it! Explain how the entry is supposed to look like.

Comment: To place the code, you have to indent each line by 4 spaces. Alternatively you select the code and click on the pair of braces just above the editing window.